# How to use a tableView as a selector to send values to another viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, tableview, viewcontroller

I'll try to explain this as best as i can, but i appologize if it gets too confusing - I've been stuck on this problem for many hours now.

In my application i have a search screen where the user will be able to select a bunch of criterias to perform the search by. Some of these criterias consists of fairly long lists of values to choose from and therefor i want a tableview on my searchscreen which have 4 rows - Each row representing a criteria that the user can set.
Once the user clicks on a row i want to push a new window in my navigationcontroller which consists of a new table containing the selectable values for that criteria - Once the user clicks on one of these rows on the new window, i want the selected value to be sent back to my main searchscreen and pop back to my search screen.

What would be the best way to do this?

**Elaboration:**

My searchscreen is called SearchViewController and is contained in a navigationController.
SearchViewController contains two sliders and a tableView with 4 rows called "Searchtype", "Property type", "Salestype", "Area" and a searchbutton. If the user clicks on "Searchtype" then i want a new view to be pushed in the navigationController which should contain a new tableView with a bunch of rows representing different possible values for the "Searchtype" criteria - The same goes for all 4 rows in SearchViewController.
When the user clicks on one of the value rows in the newly pushed tableView i want that tableView to be popped away and the selected value sent back to the SearchViewController allowing the user to either select more criterias or push the search button to actually perform a search based on the selected criterias.

But i can't figure out the best way to do this?
I really appreciate any help i can get - I'm going nuts trying to figure this out :)

Btw. i don't use Interface Builder - All UI elements are coded manually.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 ways to do it here:

1) Let the Search View Controller be the delegate of action in the Search Type View Controller, so that when the user selects a search type, it will be informed. Use protocol for proper check at compile time if you want, and remember to use assign instead of retain for the delegate, to avoid circular reference.

2) Set the UINavigationController delegate to Search View Controller (or whatever class you want to control it), and listen to the event when the Search Type View Controller is popped out.

3) Implement a "refresh" function in viewWillAppear: as suggested above, but this is not recommended, because the implementation of viewWillAppear: sucks and not reliable at all. Maybe good for simple app, but when the structure of your app gets complicated, forget it.

4) Use NSNotificationCenter. Your Search View Controller will observe all changes to search criteria, and in each child view controller, when the user changes it, post a notification. This is more complicated, but much more powerful and flexible than all the methods above.

5) Similarly, you can use Core Data to store all search criteria in an object, and listen to changes in that object using KVO. This is a bit more advanced and may be overkill, but if you know KVO, it makes life much easier in Objective C, so probably worth taking a look anyway.

Btw: It's good to do all the UI by hand coding to understand the concepts at first, but try to move to Interface Builder whenever you can. It is a much recommended way to work (there are countless threads on this in Stackoverflow or on the web, with more elaborated discussions on why IB is better).

Comment: Thanks a lot - Really appreciate all the help while learning :)

Comment: Would you by any chance have a few links for some of the better articles on the subject of IB vs manual UI?

Comment: Jeff La Marche (one of the best blogger for iPhone dev imo) has a good post about it: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/dont-fear-interface-builder.html. But be aware that Interface Builder has a really steep learning curve, and may be very confusing at first, but don't give up too easily. If you are going to work on iPhone (or Mac) development for a long time, then it will pay off greatly.

Comment: I think IB is a great tool and it's definitely worth using it! I must admit I kind of feel good, because year ago, everyone here in the Czech republic was talking about performance issues of IB, about increased complexity of development, about the "real guys do the UI in the code" etc. - and now, it's been shown it was just a bogus talk...